# The term '\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I have been trying to get a venv to activate for the last week. Currently, the errors say The module 'venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module venv' but when I run that, the terminal tells me:
Import-Module : The specified module 'venv' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module

I have virtualenv installed and updated. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both the package and Python3 trying to fix.

I have added python and the parent directory of the project to PATH. With no results. I 've been working on this for the last week and given up more then a few times with nothing. Can anyone please help me?   Python version 3.10.1

Should I roll my version of python back?

PS C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test\Scripts> \venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 : The term '\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- \venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test\Scripts> cd..
PS C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test> \venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 : The term '\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- \venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test> venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 : The module 'venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module venv'.
At line:1 char:1

- venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv\Scripts\activate.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
  ```

PS C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test> Import-Module venv
Import-Module : The specified module 'venv' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.
At line:1 char:1

- Import-Module venv
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (venv:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
  ```

Comment: what happens if you do the sensible, safe thing and _use the full path_?

Comment: @ Lee_Dailey
Unless I'm mistaken the full path is "C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test" 
         If I'm incorrect in my assumption please let me know and provide an example. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this try next:

1. Go to the root folder with your project.

[image: pic_1]

2. Type next: venv/scripts/activate (where venv is the name of your envirement)

[image: pic_2]

3.To deactivate it just enter deactivate.

Comment: I get the same error as in the original post. While I'm in the root directory, the command for me would be "venv-test/scrips/activate"  (my project is called "venv-test") Also, I have used with and without ".ps1" and the error I continue to get is the same: "venv-test/scripts/activate : The term 'venv-test/scripts/activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv-test/scripts/activate"

Comment: I'm 100% sure there's some other error happening. I'm trying to run an email script using "smtplib" and getting an import error on 'email.message' which is prepackaged in python. 

What would be my next possible steps to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Using the full path to the activate.ps1 script  must work, otherwise something is not correctly setup in your venv environment.

```
C:\Users\Corey\Development_Cortuga\venv-test\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

If the above still does not work, make sure py.exe and venv are available from your Powershell session:

```
py.exe -h
py.exe -m venv -h
```

Comment: While using the full path (in the root directory of the project) still doesn't work, It appears both "py.exe -h"  &  "py.exe -m venv -h" work and give me help type info on flags, options & arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I know im late to the party but try this one command, it worked for me:

```
.\activate.ps1
```

Step by step:

1. cd *project folder*

   > `cd mywebsite`
2. enter venv and scripts

   > `cd venv/scripts`
3. run command

   > `.\activate.ps1`